# Appropriate value of convergence plane distance in a 360° stereoscopic VR video

Tags: camera, stereoscopy, panoramic, vr

How to determine the appropriate value convergence plane distance？
I'm working on a panoramic stereoscopic video for Meta Quest 2. I use the stereo camera in off-axis mode. With the Spherical Stereo option checked, it works together with the panorama type.
After some rendering tests, I got some stereoscopic effects in the default convergence plane distance (1.95m), but I still wonder about this value.
After watching this video([VRLA Summer Expo 2016: How VR Works A Perceptual Point of View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJ0TV2jgNoc)), I guess it may be related to the focal distance of the VR headset. In the case of Quest 2, the focal distance is 1.3m, which is somewhat close to the Blender default value of 1.95m.
However, it is said that the focal distance of some VRs is at infinity, so if I make a video for those VRs, how do I take the value.

Comment: I use a value based on camera position and the most interesting part of the scene. Could be a meter or two, could be an inch or two. The camera shows the convergence plane so you can adjust it to suit.

Answer (score 0):

I think these settings are designed with a 3D TV scenario, where the convergence place is the distance of the TV, object closer than the convergence will appear pop-out of the TV screen, and object far away will appear into the screen. For VR with Blender I set the convergence plane to the main stage, where the main object is located, and then I divide that number by 30, and set it as the interocular distance. The interocular distance is what really matters, you do not set it to around 65mm unless everything in your scene is in real life scale.